# How do I add a user to the sudoers file?

Tags: sudo

I already know that I should:

- run **visudo**
- be logged in as root

But then what changes should I make to the sudoers file?

p.s. The question got 'down-voted'.  Is this a bad question?!  I looked at man sudoers, and there are several pages of explanation of everything to do with the sudoers file, most of it in Extended Backus-Naur Form.  I want to know something much more specific and I don't have 3 hours to waste finding out how.  In other words, I want a simple example for someone with not that much experience.

Comment: `man visudo`, SEE ALSO section

Comment: You make whatever changes are required to effect the configuration change you wish to make.

Comment: Your original question appears to suggest that you haven't invested any time in reading the manuals or other online resources. You haven't said what you want the user to do, full permissions on all commands all hosts, restricted use of particular command on one host. You could even have looked at the `Questions with similar titles` or the `related` questions that this system presents to you. You didn't, you chose to whine, the online community will be a better place without you. I have on many occasions pointed colleagues to the manuals too.

Comment: in respect to your p.s addition. *what are you trying to do ?!* I'm assuming you want to add a user to give them the ability to do what ? run every command through sudo ?? what ? The key problem word in "something much more specific" is "something"

Answer (score 1):

It's a bad question because you've given no information about what you're trying to achieve. Someone could say run "`sudo visudo`", append "#username" to the bottom of the file, save, done.

Do you want the user to be able run commands as root? With or without a password? The sudoers file is both flexible and complicated.

For simply allowing the user to run commands as root you would usually add them to a predefined group that is already in the file such as as "admin" or "sudo".

I.E:

```
usermod -a -G admin username
```